# A graph and its complement are paths

Tags: graph-theory

i am new to graph theory and in one of the lectures notes i found a lemma about the paths of a graph and its complements?

LEMMA:**There are only two graphs such that their complements are also paths:The path on 2 nodes on three vertices and the path on 4 nodes**

i really don't understand this lemma, Can someone please explain the proof and what it means?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does "path on 2 nodes on three vertices" mean? What's the difference between nodes and vertices? I thought they were different names for the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complement of a graph is what you get when you replace (a) all the edges with non-edges, and (b) all the non-edges with edges.

So, here's the 4-node path and its complement:

[image: the 4-node path]

The complement also happens to be a path.

The complement of a path on 2 nodes is the null graph on 2 nodes (i.e., 2 nodes, no edges), drawn below.  This would generally not be regarded as a path, so this is an error in the statement given.

[image: 2-node path and its complement]

If the single vertex graph is considered a path, then its complement is also a path.

So probably the statement should be:

> There are only two *paths* such that their complements are also paths: *the path on 1 node*, and the path on 4 nodes.

Oh, and the proof is essentially: (a) check small cases, then (b) for $n \geq 5$ nodes, the complement has a vertex of degree $ \geq 3$, so cannot be a path.

Comment: Or, since a path on $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges, and since the complete graph on $n$ vertices has $n(n-1)/2$ edges, you could solve the equation $2(n-1)=n(n-1)/2.$ The solutions are $n=1,4,$ so $n\in\{1,4\}$ is a necessary condition, and is easily seen to be sufficient as well.

Comment: @rebecca the statement is as mentioned , i will clarify the first part with my colleagues  !! 
Thanks for answering fast !!

Comment: @bof sorry for the question 6 years after the fact, but I'm wondering: how did you derive 2(−1) in your given equation since the path on n vertices is n-1? Where does the 2 come from?

Comment: @GoBlue We're talking about $2$ graphs, a graph $G$ and its complement $\overline G$. If both are paths, then each of those $2$ graphs has $n-1$ edges, for a total of $2(n-1)$ edges. Each edge of the complete graph $K_n$ is an edge of just one of those two graphs, so $2(n-1)$ is equal to $n(n-1)/2$, the number of edges in the complete graph on $n$ vertices.

Comment: @bof thank you!